# How to use intended function in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I need to register in a tournament with the URL:

```
http://laravel.dev/tournaments/1/register/
```

This URL is in the middleware 'auth', so if the user is not logged, he is redirected to login / page.

What I need is to redirect to

```
http://laravel.dev/tournaments/1/register/
```

After login.

In my routes.php, I have:

```
Route::get('tournaments/{tournamentId}/register', 'TournamentController@register');
```

I was told to use

```
redirect()->intended
```

but I don't know how to do it.

In the general case, User will be redirected to /admin, but in this case, I want him to keep doing his main action ( Register tournament)...

I'm using the built in trait for login, so I checked what system do when login and it is already using this function:

```
protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
{
    if ($throttles) {
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
        return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->user());
    }

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Thing is it will redirect me to a default path, not a dynamic one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to check:

- Use your browser's inspect element network feature to trace redirects - there may be several, which could help clear up confusion.
- The `intended()` method requires a call to `guest()` when redirecting previous to the former. This happens in the `Authenticate` middleware, but 
  if you're using some other middleware (such as a middleware to catch and redirect admins to an admin area), this might be triggering first and redirecting without using `guest()`.
- Does your controller using the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait implement the `authenticated` method? If so this will be returned instead of `redirect()->intended()`.

Comment: For the first point, I will check it. For the second point, can you please tell me more, because I'm in this case. For the third point, yes, you can see it in the code.

Comment: For the second point, look at each class in `$routeMiddleware` in `app/Http/Kernel.php` to see if one contains a redirect without calling `guest()`.

Comment: For the third point, if the `authenticated()` method is implemented in your controller, you should make sure it uses `guest()`, or delete it.

Comment: I get it working, but still failing with socialite --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35022774/redirect-to-url-after-login-with-socialite-in-laravel

Answer (score 5):

You should to know different between **Redirect To** and **Redirect Intended**

```
Redirect Intended: redirects the user to where they were originally going

Redirect To: Redirect the user to the page **YOU** specify them to go.
```