# How to Return Redirect Back To Page Before Login | Laravel 8.83.23

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have a laravel app version 8.83.23.
I have multiple views that have links to show the login page. A simple example is this:

Think of a blog post. "you must login to post a comment".. The user clicks "login" and is taken to the login view (auth.login). The user fills the form and submits. The user is authenticated. I then want the authenticated user to be redirected to the page where they originally clicked login.

[image: The concept]

Is there a simple solution such as changing $redirectTo in the LoginController.php to something dynamic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use intended function in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003981/how-to-use-intended-function-in-laravel)

Comment: @CornelRaiu Not really, that question is over six years old. I do see some similarities in the question, but the auth scaffolding has changed so much since Laravel 5... Thanks for the assistance though

Comment: the `intended` method is still being used and I am using it on 15+ different projects Laravel 8 and 9: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticating-users : `The intended method provided by Laravel's redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the authentication middleware. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available.`

Comment: @CornelRaiu Thanks ... it seems like in order to use the intended() method, I would need to manually authenticate users instead of using the auth scaffolding logic. Am I understandind this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I am usually using it is with the [Laravel `intended` method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticating-users).

> The `intended` method provided by Laravel's redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the authentication middleware. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available.

We are setting the `url.intended` value in the current session so when the user visits the login page, it will check for the `url.intended` to redirect the user where they were when they clicked the login URL. If there is no `url.intended` it will just redirect to the default `RouteServiceProvider::HOME`.

The AuthenticatedSessionController.php store method is the one that came with the Inertia scaffolding in Laravel 8.83.1 ( not sure if that changed since )

MyController.php

```
class QuotesController extends Controller
{
    public function productQuote(string $product)
    {
        if (auth()->guest()) {
            session()->put('url.intended', request()->fullUrl());
        }

        return view(
            'get-product-quote',
            ['product' => $this->getProduct($product), 'user' => $this->getUser()]
        );
    }
}
```

And in the `get-product-quote` view I simply do this:

```
<x-app-layout>
    <div class="relative container mx-auto z-0 py-8 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        @guest
            <div>
                <a :href="route('login')" class="inline-block py-3 px-8 bg-itg-blue hover:bg-itg-blue-dark border border-transparent text-white text-sm rounded-sm text-center">Log in for faster quote submitting process</a>
            </div>
        @endguest

        @auth
            ... 
            <p>do the authenticated user stuff</p>
        @endauth
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

AuthenticatedSessionController.php

```
class AuthenticatedSessionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming authentication request.
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $request->authenticate();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to redirect back to the page where the user logged in

```
return back();
```

Comment: No, I did state rather clearly that the intention is for the user to be returned to the page before the login page. Thanks thouhg.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).